# Why is there an extra pixel in some world images, 43201 vs 43200?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, night-time-images

I have two images both of which have world nighttime lights. They are off by 1 pixel and the equivalent decimal degrees, but the 43201 image seems to be "too large." Using gdal:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: F152000.v4b_web.avg_vis.tif
Size is 43201, 16801
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.004166666650008,75.004166666649994)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333300000,-0.008333333300000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0041667,  75.0041667) (180d 0'15.00"W, 75d 0'15.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0041667, -65.0041661) (180d 0'15.00"W, 65d 0'15.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0041652,  75.0041667) (180d 0'14.99"E, 75d 0'15.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0041652, -65.0041661) (180d 0'14.99"E, 65d 0'15.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0000007,   5.0000003) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  5d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=43201x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

But `43201 * 0.008333333300000 = 360.0083318933`

In other image, gdalinfo gives:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: world_stable_lights.tif
Size is 43200, 21600
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.008333000354469,-0.008333000354469)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=100
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=100
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -89.9928077) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 89d59'34.11"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9856153,  90.0000000) (179d59' 8.22"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9856153, -89.9928077) (179d59' 8.22"E, 89d59'34.11"S)
Center      (  -0.0071923,   0.0035962) (  0d 0'25.89"W,  0d 0'12.95"N)
Band 1 Block=43200x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

`43200 * 0.008333000354469 = 359.99999856`. This is closer to 360 than the 360.008333... above.

Not to be picky, but it seems there is an extra pixel. I thought that the leftmost column of pixels could perhaps be a duplicate of the rightmost, that they might "overlap," but this is not the case. One system ultimately has `(-0.0000007,-0.0000007)` as the centroid of the pixel closest to `(0,0)`, whereas the other system has that centroid at `(0.0041667,0.0041667)`, off by one-half of a pixel.

I'm also confused as to why each pixel is larger in the 43201 image. 0.00000033294553 (the difference in size of each pixel) * 43201 (the 1 doesn't really matter here) = 0.01438357988, which is not close to a 1 or 1/2 pixel 'offset.' I'm new to GIS and I'm curious what is going on here. Could someone illuminate this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first raster is derived from a nodes grid.

The upper left node of the grid is in coordinates `(75, -180)`, and the upper right node of the grid is in coordinates `(75, 180)`.

We do know that both nodes are at the same geographical place. But that is how the grid was created: from longitude -180 degrees to longitude 180 degrees.

When that grid is converted to a pixels raster format, the conversion is configured to match each node with the center of the pixel cell, and that is why the raster has a half of pixel cell border to each direction.

I don't know how was derived the second raster, but note that it doesn't cover 360 degrees. The upper right corner is at coordinates (90, 179.9856153), that is 0.0143847 degrees less than 360.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean here, but if it indeed has a 1/2 pixel "cell border," then how would two images with either format be compared? What data is contained within the "cell border?" Is there the same amount of data in both images? I'm not concerned in having this data at the edges, I'm just interested in comparing two images on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

Comment: Both images are not comparable on a pixel-by-pixel basis, pixels of one image are not aligned with the pixels of the other. In the NOAA image, the 1/2 pixels border has the data of the node to wich that 1/2 pixel corresponds. It is a grid of nodes. Think of it as the nodes are not points but rectangular cells and you have the raster version.